# Struts2 if condition using string list

Tags: java, struts2

I have Array list called matrixList, on which i am iterating. I want to display different value if return value from getStatus() method equals to value "GREEN" .For some reason i am getting error 
"target is null for method equals"

```
<s:iterator status="stat" value="matrixList">
  <tr>
    <s:if test="%{#status.equals('GREEN')}">
      THIS IS green
    </s:if>

    <td class="R0C1"><s:property value="status"/></td>
    <td class="R0C1"><s:property value="releaseTarget"/></td>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `status` isn't null?

Comment: yes, Status value is not null. it have value 'GREEN', I displayed it at separate column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit `#` if `status` is on the value stack (as opposed to a named value in the stack context):

```
<s:if test="%{status.equals('GREEN')}">
```

If `<s:property value="status"/>` works why reference it differently in the `<s:if>` tag?

Comment: Thanks. Removing '#' sign fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The property name used in the `if` statement should be `stat` and not `status`.

```
<s:if test="%{#stat.equals('GREEN')}">
```

This is because the name of the variable in the iteration scope is defined as `stat` in the `status = "stat"` statement.

Comment: But i want to compare against value return by getStatus() Method.<td class="R0C1"><s:property value="status"/></td>

Comment: `status="stat"` is an attribute of `<s:iterator>` tag which **isn't** current iteration element.

Comment: it is also current iteration element as well, just like releaseTarget as shown above.